# Difference in usage of "rock" and "rocks"

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

Recently, I came across this situation where I was asked which one was correct:

> Fossils are found in sedimentary rock.
>
> Fossils are found in sedimentary rocks.

Is there is distinction between these statements?

Answer (score 12):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but in general the first is true and the second false.   “Sedimentary rock” refers to sedimentary rock structures or sedimentary rocks in general; “sedimentary rocks” refers to pieces of sedimentary rock.  The first statement suggests that fossils may be found in sedimentary rock, which typically is so.  The second statement suggests that if I have a sedimentary rock it will have a fossil in it.  But most sedimentary rocks – for example, most pieces of limestone gravel – do not have fossils in them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see the subtle difference between the two more clearly now. It threw me off a little, and I wasn't sure if I had rationalised it correctly. This is a relief!

Comment: This answer rocks. +1.

Comment: In actual fact, I believe a lot of sedimentary rocks do have microscopic fossils in them.

Answer (score 5):

*Rocks* is used when you have a countable group of rocks.  For instance:

> I found this coin under the rocks over there.

Rock can also be used in an *uncountable* sense when it refers to a big mass of rock, or "rock" as a general concept.

> Rock is a common building material.

Your example sounds like it's a general rule rather than a specific finding, which indicates that it's talking about rock as a *concept*.  Thus the correct usage is:

> Fossils are found in sedimentary rock.

If you were talking about fossils that were actually *in* [individual rocks](http://www.geography-site.co.uk/pages/virtual-school/lessons/linkpages/008/images/sed01.jpg), it might be possible to turn the sentence around, but that does not fit your specific example.

> I found these fossils in those rocks over there.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the other answers are correct in that *rocks* usually refers to individual discrete rocks. However,

> Fossils are found in sedimentary rocks.

could also refer to multiple *types* of sedimentary rock. For example,

> Fossils are found in sedimentary rocks, such as chalk and limestone.

sounds correct. It might be less ambiguous to say *... sedimentary rock types ...* explicitly, though.